# How to replace an element on a HTML page with another element after a video ends, then change back after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, html

I've been tasked with creating a sort of Kiosk to display in an office, the Kiosk is suppose to cycle through the various advertising videos that I've been given, this part is easy enough as I found another post about that, however after each video they want a news stream to play for 10 minutes, then for the kiosk to go to the next video, and continue like this. the stream I'm trying to use is the embedded iframe for the sky news YouTube stream

```
<iframe
    width="560"
    height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Auq9mYxFEE?controls=0"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I've tried a few things like trying to hide the existing element and show the other, but unfortunately I've never used HTML before being tasked with this so it's going about as well as can be expected

This is what I'm doing to display and cycle through the videos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<video src="Video1.mp4" id="video" autoplay></video>

<script>
var vidElement = document.getElementById('video');
    var vidSources = [
      "Video1.mp4",
      "video2.mp4",
      "Video3.mp4"
      ];
    var activeVideo = Math.floor((Math.random() * vidSources.length));
    vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
    vidElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      // update the active video index
      activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % vidSources.length;
      if(activeVideo === vidSources.length){
        activeVideo = 0;
      }

      // update the video source and play
      vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
      vidElement.play();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I've tried adding to the existing script to preform the task of hiding the stream, by either setting the display of the element to none or by changing the hight and width to 0, neither of which worked for me. so either,

---

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Auq9mYxFEE?controls=0&autoplay=1" title="YouTube video player" id="youtubeplay" frameborder="0"</iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById("youtubeplay").style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

or

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Auq9mYxFEE?controls=0&autoplay=1" title="YouTube video player" id="youtubeplay" frameborder="0"</iframe>

<script>
var liveElement = document.getElementById('youtubeplay');
    liveElement.display = 'block'
    liveElement.style.max-height = '0%';
    liveElement.style.max-width = '0%';
</script>
```

I haven't gotten as far as trying to change the video back after 10 minutes as my attempts at hiding the video to start with didn't work, any help would be appreciated.

Please also let me know if this is the completely wrong way of trying to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it with jquery like this:

```
`$("#youtubeplay").removeAttr("hidden");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#youtubeplay").prop("hidden", "true");
    },600000)`
```

The code is deleting attribute hidden from the element with the id "youtubeplay" and after 10 minutes (`60'0000` milliseconds) adds it back so the video disappears, I hope you know jQuery but if you don't here's a code in regular JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("youtubeplay").removeAttribute("hidden");
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("youtubeplay").setAttribute("hidden", "true");
},600000)
```